# Evaluating multiplication with exponential function

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

I'm trying to come up with a good way to evaluate the following function

```
double foo(std::vector<double> const& x, double c = 0.95)
{
   auto N = x.size(); // Small power of 2 such as 512 or 1024
   double sum = 0;
   for (auto i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
     sum += (x[i] * pow(c, double(i)/N));
   }
   return sum;
}
```

My two main concerns with this naive implementation are performance and accuracy.  So I suspect that the most trivial improvement would be to reverse the loop order: `for (auto i = N-1; i != -1; --i)` (The -1 wraps around, this is OK). This improves accuracy by adding smaller terms first.

While this is good for accuracy, it keeps the performance problem of `pow`. Numerically, `pow(c, double(i)/N)` is `pow(c, (i-1)/N) * pow(c, 1/N)`. And the latter is a constant. So in theory we can replace `pow` with repeated multiplication. While good for performance, this hurts accuracy - errors will accumulate.

I suspect that there's a significantly better algorithm hiding in here. For instance, the fact that N is a power of two means that there is a middle term x[N/2] that's multiplied with `sqrt(c)`. That hints at a recursive solution.

On a somewhat related numerical observation, this looks like a signal multiplication with an exponential, so I naturally think : "FFT, trivial convolution=shift, IFFT", but that seems to offer no real benefit in terms of accuracy or performance.

So, is this a well-known problem with known solutions?

Comment: if `c` don't vary too much, you could create tables for `pow(c, ...)`

Comment: btw, this is not convolution, just a simple dot product, so I don't think FFT has any use here

Comment: @geza: Agree. It's a multiplication; the FFT would turn it into a (trivial) convolution. But the price of the FFT and IFFT seem to high (O N log N).

Comment: Yep. FFT should be used only when convolution is needed, to make the algorithm from O(N^2) to O(N logN). But your algorithm is already the best possible, O(N), so you cannot do any better by switching algorithm. You can just optimize it, so the constant factor will be smaller.

Comment: What is the range of `c` ?

Comment: This is simply polynomial evaluation. The Horner scheme is an efficient method for that and reduces errors due to the minimal operation count.

Comment: @LutzL: the value of the variable is very close to 1 so that evaluation of the powers as products won't be so accurate.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: `[0.5 , 1.0)` I think. But it's certainly not uniformly distributed over that range. I've show 0.95 as a default because it's a typical value. And indeed, 0.95^(1/1024) is approximately 0.99995.

Comment: @LutzL: Horner's scheme is one way to "replace pow with repeated multiplication", as I mentioned in the second paragraph. But Yves is right, the problem here is the numerical accuracy of values like 0.99995. That's approximately 14 bits of wasted precision.

Comment: [To the person that tries to remove the C++ tag - see LutzL's answer. Relevant C++ functions like `expm1` justifiy the C++tag. ]

Comment: @MSalters Do you really think this question is a C++ question and not generic to most languages

Comment: @Pi: C++11 didn't have the `expm1` function, so even the version matters.

Comment: @MSalters: Most math libraries had this earlier, since C99 it is in the standard for math.h/cmath, C++11 only unified the C++ template so that there is no longer an `expm1f`.

Comment: @MSalters [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/expm1) states expm1 should be there since C++11. Or am I somehow mistaken?

Comment: @Pi: Could have sworn it was added in '14. Still, it's not a function you find in every language, that was my point. E.g. Javascript doesn't have it.

Comment: @MSalters Got it. Sorry for the trouble :D

Comment: Is it really only one value that you compute or are you computing an exponentially dampened moving average? In the latter case convolution techniques with accelerations via FFT methods are advisable.

Comment: @LutzL: We indeed calculate 1 value for every N inputs. However, we do this several thousands of times per second, as we can easily have millions of inputs per second.

Comment: And the inputs are always different, not from a shifting window of the input sequence? That is, x[0..N-1], then x[N..2N-1], etc instead of x[0..N-1], then x[1..N], then x[2..N+1] etc.? And in the mass evaluation, is the c always the same for a long time or does it change often?

Comment: @LutzL: Indeed. Zero overlap. Each input contributes to one output, each output depends only on `N` inputs and the current value of `c`.

Answer (score 2):

Yves' answer inspired me.

It seems that the best approach is to not calculate `pow(c, 1.0/N)` directly, but indirectly:

`cc[0]=c; cc[1]=sqrt(cc[0]), cc[2]=sqrt(cc[1]),... cc[logN] = sqrt(cc[logN-1])`

Or in binary,

`cc[0]=c, cc[1]=c^0.1, cc[2]=c^0.01, cc[3]=c^0.001, ...`.

Now if we need `x[0b100100] * c^0.100100`, we can calculate that as `x[0b100100]* c^0.1 * c^0.0001`. I don't need to precalculate a table of size N, as geza suggested. A table of size log(N) is probably sufficient, and it can be created by repeatedly taking square roots.

[edit]
As pointed out in a comment thread on another answer, pairwise summation is very effective in keeping errors under control. And it happens to combine extremely nicely with this answer.

We start by observing that we sum

```
x[0] * c^0.0000000
x[1] * c^0.0000001
x[2] * c^0.0000010
x[3] * c^0.0000011
...
```

So, we run log(N) iterations. In iteration 1, we add the N/2 pairs `x[i]+x[i+1]*c^0.000001` and store the result in `x[i/2]`. In iteration 2, we add the pairs `x[i]+x[i+1]*c^0.000010`, etcetera. The chief difference with normal pairwise summation is that this is a multiply-and-add in each step.

We see now that in each iteration, we're using the same multiplier `pow(c, 2^i/N)`, which means we only need to calculate log(N) multipliers. It's also quite cache-efficient, as we're doing only contiguous memory access. It also allows for easy SIMD parallelization, especially when you have FMA instructions.

Answer (score 2):

The task is a polynomial evaluation. The method for a single evaluation with the least operation count is the Horner scheme. In general a low operation count will reduce the accumulation of floating point noise.

As the example value `c=0.95` is close to `1`, any root will be still closer to `1` and thus lose accuracy. Avoid that by computing the difference to `1` directly, `z=1-c^(1/n)`, via

```
z = -expm1(log(c)/N).
```

Now you have to evaluate the polynomial

```
sum of x[i] * (1-z)^i
```

which can be done by careful modification of the Horner scheme. Instead of

```
for(i=N; i-->0; ) {
  res = res*(1-z)+x[i]
}
```

use

```
for(i=N; i-->0; ) {
  res = (res+x[i])-res*z
}
```

which is mathematically equivalent but has the loss of digits in `1-z` happening as late as possible without using more involved method like doubly accurate addition.

---

In tests those two methods contrary to the intent gave almost the same results, a substantial improvement could be observed by separating the result into its value at `c=1, z=0` and a multiple of `z` as in

```
double res0 = 0, resz=0;
int i;
for(i=N; i-->0; ) { 
    /* res0+z*resz = (res0+z*resz)*(1-z)+x[i]; */
    resz = resz - res0 -z*resz;
    res0 = res0 + x[i];
}
```

The test case that showed this improvement was for the coefficient sequence of

```
f(u) = (1-u/N)^(N-2)*(1-u)
```

where for `N=1000` the evaluations result in

```
   c               z=1-c^(1/N)             f(1-z)         diff for 1st proc     diff for 3rd proc

  0.950000     0.000051291978909      0.000018898570629  1.33289104579937e-17  4.43845264361253e-19
  0.951000     0.000050239954368      0.000018510931892  1.23765066121009e-16  -9.24959978401696e-19
  0.952000     0.000049189034371      0.000018123700958  1.67678642238461e-17  -5.38712954453735e-19
  0.953000     0.000048139216599      0.000017736876972  -2.86635949350855e-17  -2.37169225231204e-19
...
  0.994000     0.000006018054217      0.000002217256601  1.31645860662263e-17  1.15619997300212e-19
  0.995000     0.000005012529261      0.000001846785028  -4.15668713370839e-17  -3.5363625547867e-20
  0.996000     0.000004008013365      0.000001476685973  8.48811716443534e-17    8.470329472543e-22
  0.997000     0.000003004504507      0.000001106958687  1.44711343873661e-17  -2.92226366802734e-20
  0.998000     0.000002002000667      0.000000737602425   5.6734266807093e-18  -6.56450534122083e-21
  0.999000     0.000001000499833      0.000000368616443  -3.72557383333555e-17  1.47701370177469e-20
```

Comment: "with the least operation count": for the evaluation of these powers, *as far as error accumulation is concerned*, Horner's scheme achieves the worst operation count, O(N). It is possible to design solutions with O(Log N) operations only.

Comment: For polynomial evaluation with a general coefficient sequence you get no better than O(N) as each of the N coefficient has to be included in the procedure. Thus N multiplications and N additions is rather low. Multi-point evaluation is another problem where Fourier or interpolation based techniques get better complexities than O(N) per sample point.

Comment: No, I am not talking about the time complexity, I am talking about error accumulation in single-point evaluation. [By the way, the method I am referring to keeps an O(N) time complexity.]

Comment: `expm1` seems to be a crucial step in avoiding a loss of precision.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Are you thinking of pairwise addition? That might benefit my answer even more, I think. I'd first add `x[i] + c^(1/N)*x[i+1]` for all even `i`, store the result in `x[i]`. Then add `x[i] + c^(2/N) * x[i+2]`, store in `x[i]`, etcetera.

Comment: @MSalters: is there anything known about the distribution of the Xi's ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: `StDev(x)  > Average(x)`, measured samples of a continuous physical signal so non-trivial correlation between adjacent values (definitely not IID).

Comment: @MSalters: if the range of values is large, it may be useful to add from smaller to larger, preferably using a linear-time sort.

Answer (score 1):

If `N` is a power of `2`, you can replace the evaluations of the powers by geometric means, using

```
a^(i+j)/2 = √(a^i.a^j)
```

and recursively subdivide from `c^N/N.c^0/N`. With preorder recursion, you can make sure to accumulate by increasing weights.

Anyway, the speedup of `sqrt` vs. `pow` might be marginal.

You can also stop recursion at a certain level and continue linearly, with mere products.

Answer (score 0):

You could mix repeated multiplication by `pow(c, 1./N)` with some explicit `pow` calls. I.e. every 16th iteration or so do a real `pow` and otherwise move forward with the multiply. This should yield large performance benefits at negligible accuracy cost.

Depending on how much `c` varies, you might even be able to precompute and replace all pow calls with a lookup, or just the ones needed in the above method (= smaller lookup table = better caching).

Comment: A slightly more logical choice would be every 8th or 16th iteration; 10 doesn't divide 1024.